# Caching supported for callable functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I was wondering whether it is possible to apply cache-control settings to the response of a callable function. We've used http triggers before and switched to callable functions but cannot find any way to take over the cache-control header.

To be more specific: a http-triggered cloud function allows a cache setting like this:

```
exports.myFunc = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200');
  ...
}
```

When we migrated to a callable function

```
exports.myFunc = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  ... 
  /* no res-object for cache-control? */
  ...
})
```

which gets called in our app as follows:

```
const myFunc = functions.httpsCallable('myFunc');
myFunc({params}).then(result => ...)
```

we couldn't find a way to apply cache settings anywhere.

Comment: Please edit your question to describe what exactly have you tried that didn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Did you resolve this in any way? I'm trying to figure it out, how to implement cache feature in callable functions, but for now, no idea :/

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I went back to using Cloud Functions via axios GET-calls

Comment: I am also looking for a solution on this.

Comment: same here. for me some functions don't need to send upto date info.

Comment: Hey @DougStevenson since you work on Firebase, perhaps you could simply answer if it's possible or not?

Comment: This would've been so handy!

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to set response headers with callable functions.  If this is important to you, please [file a feature request.](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support)

Comment: I use `context.rawRequest.res!.setHeader()` and I see this header as a result in my browser, but caching is not happened. One question, is it this method valid for callable firebase functions?

Comment: Has this changed in 2022 at all?

Comment: According to the doc "Only GET and HEAD requests can be cached. HTTPS requests using other methods are never cached." Callable functions are POST requests so never cached